# MSSQL trigger or constraint to prevent or allow update/delete based on column value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of Customers, and I want to prevent update/insert when the row has Status column that is anything other than 1.

What would be the best way to create that kind of functionality direstly on server?

Comment: So if someone inserts/updates row and this new row status <> 1 - trigger must prevent updating/inserting?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a stored procedure and force its usage to update the table.

```
create procedure updateCustomers @custID int,@newValue nvarchar(50) 
with execute as superUser 
as

update customers
set someColumn=@newValue
where custID=@custID and status=1
```

Comment: This will only work if the this Stored Proc is used.  Nothing here prevents an update using a straight update statement or SSMS

Comment: you can deny the right to update the table to regular users and add a execute as clause in the procedure to impersonate a super user that can update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[PreventUpdate]
ON [dbo].[Customers]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF EXISTS 
  (
     SELECT 1 FROM Customers c
       WHERE c.Status <> 1 )
  BEGIN
     RAISERROR(...);
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
     --You update code
  END
END
GO
```

Comment: I think that what he wants is preventing the update when the row has a status other than 1. Here it will prevent any update if any row has a status different of 1.

Comment: DoubleT28 - you are right. But I can change the select inside the trigger to  achieve that.

Comment: Why `SELECT 1 FROM Customers c` ...` ? This will be very likely for one scan on `Customers` table. It should be `FROM inserted / deleted`.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to prevent any INSERT/UPDATE action when the new `Status` is diff. that 1 then following trigger will prevent such actions. **Anyways, this requirement makes no sense because it's much simple to use a check constraint thus: `ALTER TABLE dbo.Customer ADD CONSTRAINT ... CHECK ([Status] <> 1)`**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgIU_Customer_PreventIU
ON dbo.Customer
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted i WHERE i.[Status] IS NOT NULL AND i.[Status] <> 1)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Can''t insert or update rows with Status <> 1', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK
    END
END
```

2) But if you want to simply avoid any **update** when current `[Status]` is 1 then following trigger could be used:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgU_Customer_PreventU
ON dbo.Customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted d WHERE d.[Status] = 1)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Can''t update rows with Status = 1', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way

Do not use a trigger for this purpose.  Triggers exist to enforce referential integrity, and using them for other purposes will lead to tears.

Deny users privileges on the table, and provide stored procedures instead, such as [doublet28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6408749/doublet28) suggests.  That gives you the opportunity to provide a meaningful error message, and leaves the DBA free to update the table without tripping on the trigger (which will be needed sooner than later).